# Невозможно запустить это приложение на вашем пк

Tags: windows, openserver

Я хочу скачать openserver. После запуска exe файла выходит сообщение Невозможно запустить это приложение на вашем пк. У меня 64-х битная система, я пробовала запуск от имени администратора - бесполезно. Что с этим делать?

Comment: А вы уверены, что скачали 64 битную версию опенсервера?

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть, какие dll хочет программа, http://www.dependencywalker.com

Comment: Можно ссылку на скачивание добавить в вопрос?